# How to detect if phone is moving?

Tags: android, accelerometer, gyroscope

right now I'm working on an app that heavily relies on Geofencing API.
It works fine, however sometimes when I leave phone on my desk, I sometimes receive false-positive callbacks. Probably because I switch between 3G antennas or something.

My idea was to detect user movement. If user is not moving and I receive message that he left the area - I'll know its wrong. Unfortunately I can't rely on location services, because apparently LocationManager and Geofencing API are giving me weird data. 
Sometimes when I enter an area and trigger `getLastLocation()`, it's few kilometers away. Sometimes when I'm notified about leaving the area... Location Services are informing me that I'm still where I should. So yea - can't really rely on that.

Is there some kind of callback, notification or whole library for receiving notification of some sorts that phone is moving? From accelerometer or gyroscope?

Yes, I could micro manage that, because my app already has a service... but I'd like to avoid heavy battery drainage.

Comment: Were you able to find out the solution?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use google play services activity recognition

https://dzone.com/articles/android-activity-recognition